# TileMill: How to mask layer without losing background

Tags: layers, tilemill, mapbox, cartocss

I have a large geotiff with elevation gradient which I want to use to colour my map. However, the coastal line of the geotiff doesn't exactly match my shapefile so I want to mask it. The problem is that by using comp-op options (the best result is by using dst-in) I lose my background. Does anyone have a clue how to mask my layer but keep the background?

Attached is a screenshot for more explanation.

[image: Screenshot of my TileMill project, with arrows pointing to the layers.]

Answer (score 1):

The only way I've been able to do this is by creating two projects (background and masked image), uploading them both to MapBox, and combining them as a Project.

Not ideal, as you have to maintain two different projects, and store them both online.

Comment: Yeah I thought that. Luckily I found a shape file with the coastline and the ocean which I could use as an overlay and therefore it fitted my masked areas.